# Increase TextView by integer variable

Tags: android, onclick, textview, integer, addition

I have a button with a simple onClick method. Everytime when the button is clicked i want my TextView to increase by 1. For example my TextView shows 0
and when the button is clicked it schould show 1 and when the button is clicked again it should show 2...and so on. I hope my point is clear ;)

public class game extends Activity {

```
ViewGroup layout;
TextView score1;
String score;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    score1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    score = score1.getText().toString();

    layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);
    layout.setOnTouchListener(
            new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    String presentValStr=score1.getText().toString();
                    int presentIntVal=Integer.parseInt(presentValStr);
                    presentIntVal++;
                    score1.setText(String.valueOf(presentIntVal));

                    return true;
                }
            }

                );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private int count=0; 

@Override public void onClick(View v) {
     count++;
     textView.setText(Integer.toString(count));
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you, your code is working but the textview allways increase by a random number and not by the number 1.

Comment: Do you mean that this code increases by a random number? I can help you better if you showed me your code.

Comment: I put my code in the question section.

Comment: It is not random but you should use setOnClickListener instead of setOnTouchListener, because OnTouch detects 3 actions (ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP) so your code gets executed 3 times when you just click the view once.